# Subtract values at each index from list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Hi I want to get values of x at each index from x to calculate y preferably using a for
loop for all indexes

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
indexes_for_x =[0,1,2,3]

#subtract values of x at each index from x to calculate y
# for index 0 since x = 1 result should look like below
y_at_index_0 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Try `list.pop(item_number)`.

Comment: Are you saying, for each `n` in `indexes_for_x`, you want to produce the array `x - n`?  What have you tried?  It's not hard.

Comment: It's not clear what `indexes_for_x` is for in the code.

Comment: @Mark it is the index for x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. If you want to subtract each value  from `x[<indexes_for_x>]` then you can do:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
indexes_for_x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for v in indexes_for_x:
    print(f"y_at_index_{v} = {[w - x[v] for w in x]}")
```

Prints:

```
y_at_index_0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y_at_index_1 = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y_at_index_2 = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y_at_index_3 = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: if x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]] instead, will it still work? what code should i write for that?

Comment: @sql_nerd Flatten the list `x` first.